# How to remove dictionary outer curly bracket or append it without curly bracket into a list?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, append

```
data = [

]
for x in range(0, len(directory_files)):
    # print(directory_files[x])
    # print(os.stat('Data\\' + directory_files[x]).st_size)
    img = ("Data\\" + directory_files[x])
    img_with_no_tag = directory_files[x]
    size_of_img = str(os.stat('Data\\' + directory_files[x]).st_size)
    img_capsulated = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img_capsulated_rgb = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    parent_tag = img_with_no_tag + size_of_img
    contourIndexNo = 0
    listTest = {
        img_with_no_tag + size_of_img: {
            'filename': img_with_no_tag,
            'size': size_of_img,
            'regions': [
            ],
            'file_attributes': {
                'caption': '',
                'public_domain': 'no',
                'image_url': ''
            }
        }
    }
    # print(*listTest, sep="{}")
    data.append(listTest)
```

This is how I execute the code. The output is shown like this:

```
[
{
    "138_mask.png4776": {
        "filename": "138_mask.png",
        "size": "4776",
        "regions": [
            {
                "shape_attributes": {
                    "name": "polygon",
                    "all_points_x": [
                        299,
                        294,
                        255,
                        245,
                        227,
                        229,
                        207,
                        200,
                        219,
                        209,
                        248,
                        251,
                        330,
                        341,
                        394,
                        407,
                        441,
                        447,
                        475,
                        485,
                        424,
                        438
                    ],
                    "all_points_y": [
                        517,
                        540,
                        534,
                        610,
                        610,
                        772,
                        778,
                        838,
                        843,
                        922,
                        928,
                        949,
                        955,
                        937,
                        943,
                        825,
                        827,
                        795,
                        799,
                        714,
                        673,
                        556
                    ]
                },
                "region_attributes": {
                    "name": "rooftop",
                    "type": "rooftop",
                    "image_quality": {
                        "good": true
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "file_attributes": {
            "caption": "",
            "public_domain": "no",
            "image_url": ""
        }
    }
},
{----------------------------------------> cannot remove it
    "332_mask.png8391": {
        "filename": "332_mask.png",
        "size": "8391",
        "regions": [
            {
```

....

However, I would like to get the desired output like this:

```
"138_mask.png4776": {
    "filename": "138_mask.png",
    "size": 4776,
    "regions": [
        {
            "shape_attributes": {
                "name": "polygon",
                "all_points_x": [
                    214,
                    209,
                    218,
                    200,
                    209,
                    223,
                    252,
                    300,
                    433,
                    455,
                    476,
                    407,
                    398,
                    328,
                    250
                ],
                "all_points_y": [
                    921,
                    921,
                    843,
                    835,
                    782,
                    613,
                    535,
                    518,
                    552,
                    680,
                    794,
                    861,
                    948,
                    962,
                    953
                ]
            },
            "region_attributes": {
                "name": "not_defined",
                "type": "unknown",
                "image_quality": {
                    "good": true,
                    "frontal": true,
                    "good_illumination": true
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "file_attributes": {
        "caption": "",
        "public_domain": "no",
        "image_url": ""
    }
},
"332_mask.png8391": {  ------------------------------> here what I want
    "filename": "332_mask.png",
    "size": 8391,
    "regions": [
        {
            "shape_attributes": {
                "name": "polygon",
                "all_points_x": [
                    137,
                    171,
                    395,
                    361
                ],
                "all_points_y": [
                    515,
                    389,
                    437,
                    567
                ]
            },
            "region_attributes": {
                "name": "not_defined",
                "type": "unknown",
                "image_quality": {
                    "good": true,
                    "frontal": true,
                    "good_illumination": true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "shape_attributes": {
                "name": "polygon",
                "all_points_x": [
                    567,
                    586,
                    814,
                    794
                ],
                "all_points_y": [
                    605,
                    464,
                    492,
                    636
                ]
            },
            "region_attributes": {
                "name": "not_defined",
                "type": "unknown",
                "image_quality": {
                    "good": true,
                    "frontal": true,
                    "good_illumination": true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "shape_attributes": {
                "name": "polygon",
                "all_points_x": [
                    451,
                    464,
                    739,
                    729
                ],
                "all_points_y": [
                    833,
                    677,
                    694,
                    845
                ]
            },
            "region_attributes": {
                "name": "not_defined",
                "type": "unknown",
                "image_quality": {
                    "good": true,
                    "frontal": true,
                    "good_illumination": true
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "file_attributes": {
        "caption": "",
        "public_domain": "no",
        "image_url": ""
    }
}
```

}

This means, while appending the dictionary values into the list, I want to put them as they are not separate objects, or is there an alternative way while writing them into a json file?

I tried feature manipulation on json file write prompt like .replace or remove but that didn't work.

Comment: How are you generating the output? If using the `json` module which it looks like you are, you should definitely clarify that this is the case.

Comment: The below comment solved the problem, however, I would like to give feedback about your comment. I made the structure not organized well. As @Rabinzel's clarification, I changed the skeleton, and now it is working well. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show as desired output is a dictionary, so just create a dictionary instead of a list. The keys of this dictionary are then your image names, such as `"138_mask.png4776"`

```py
data = {}
```

And then later on in your code add the entry to the dictionary:

```py
data[img_with_no_tag + size_of_img] = {
    'filename': img_with_no_tag,
    'size': size_of_img,
    'regions': [],
    'file_attributes': {
        'caption': '',
        'public_domain': 'no',
        'image_url': ''
    }
}
```

Finally, if you want to put this dictionary in a list, you can always do this:

```py
data = [data]
```

Comment: If I unterstand your goal right, @Jan Willem did the right thing. At the moment you have a list, where every item of that list is one dict. Your list has the length of 2 (138_mask.png4776 and 332_mask.png8391), that's why that ',' and '{' cannot be removed like in code with the wrong output. You want a list with one item, which contains a dictionary with 2 keys (138.png and 332.png)

Comment: Thank you very much dear both @Jan Willem and Rabinzel(sorry for non-annotation, the system restricted me), now it is working flawlessly. I was trying to execute a snippet that translates binary masks' object coordinates into a JSON file in order to feed the MaskRCNN model for future injections(multi-class & single class) in the reverse order.  I tried to find premade code but I couldn't, I decided to do on my own. I appreciate you all.